# Android ListView:How to solve ListView displays the contents of the dislocation

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-volley

In ListView adapter's getView method, I load userIcon by Volley,but when i scroll the listview, userIcon has dislocationed,I think because of load network resource time-consuming,how can i solve it? Here is the code：

```
public class DictationResultAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public DictationResultAdapter( Context context, ArrayList<UserScoreInfo> userInfoList, Typeface typeface, String userId ){
    mUserInfoList = userInfoList;
    mTypeface = typeface;
    mUserId = userId;
    mContext = context;

    mLayoutInflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);  
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mQueue, new UserIconBitmapCache());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if( ListUtils.isEmpty( mUserInfoList ) ){
        return 0;
    }

    return mUserInfoList.size( );
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if( ListUtils.isEmpty( mUserInfoList ) ){
        return null;
    }

    return mUserInfoList.get( position );
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if( ListUtils.isEmpty( mUserInfoList ) ){
        return 0;
    }

    return position;
}

public int getPosition( ){
    return mMyPosition;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    mViewHolder = new ViewHolder( );

    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.adapter_score_list_layout, null );
    mViewHolder.mScoreLayout = ( RelativeLayout )convertView.findViewById( R.id.scoreLayoutId );
    mViewHolder.mScoreLayout.setClickable( false );
    mViewHolder.mPositionTxt = ( TextView )convertView.findViewById( R.id.positionTxtId );
    mViewHolder.mUserNameTxt = ( TextView )convertView.findViewById( R.id.userNameTxtId );
    mViewHolder.mUserNameTxt.setTypeface( mTypeface );
    mViewHolder.mUserIconImg = ( ImageView )convertView.findViewById( R.id.userIconImgId );
    mViewHolder.mUserScoreTxt = ( TextView )convertView.findViewById( R.id.userScoreTxtId );

    showContent( position, mUserInfoList.get( position ) );
    return convertView;
}

private void showContent( int index, UserScoreInfo userInfo ){
    switch( index ){
    case 0:{
        mViewHolder.mUserIconImg.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.chinese_dictation_score_1 );
        mViewHolder.mPositionTxt.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
    }
    break;
    case 1:{
        mViewHolder.mUserIconImg.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.chinese_dictation_score_2 );
        mViewHolder.mPositionTxt.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
    }
    break;
    case 2:{
        mViewHolder.mUserIconImg.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.chinese_dictation_score_3 );
        mViewHolder.mPositionTxt.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
    }
    break;
    default:{
        handleUserIcon( mImageLoader, userInfo, mUserId );

        mViewHolder.mPositionTxt.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        mViewHolder.mPositionTxt.setText( "第" + userInfo.getScoreRank( ) + "名" );
    }
    break;
    }

    if( mUserId.equals( userInfo.getUserId( ) ) ){
        mMyPosition = index;
        mViewHolder.mScoreLayout.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.chinese_dictation_score_list_select );
    }else{
        mViewHolder.mScoreLayout.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.chinese_dictation_score_list_normal );
    }

    String userName = userInfo.getNickName( );
    if( !TextUtils.isEmpty( userName ) ){
        userName = ( userName.length( ) > 10 )?( userName.substring(0, 7) + "..." ):userName;
    }else{
        userName = "匿名";
    }

    if( mUserId.equals( userInfo.getUserId( ) ) ){
        String localUserName = PersonalInfo.getCurrentUserName( mContext );
        mMyPosition = index;
        mViewHolder.mScoreLayout.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.chinese_dictation_score_list_select );
        if( TextUtils.isEmpty( userName ) || ( !localUserName.equals( userName ) ) ){
            mViewHolder.mUserNameTxt.setText( localUserName  );
        }else{
            mViewHolder.mUserNameTxt.setText( userName  );
        }

    }else{
        mViewHolder.mScoreLayout.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.chinese_dictation_score_list_normal );
        mViewHolder.mUserNameTxt.setText( userName );
    }

    mViewHolder.mUserScoreTxt.setText( StringUtils.getSplitByComma( userInfo.getScore( ) + "" ) );
}

public void handleUserIcon(ImageLoader imageLoader, final UserScoreInfo userInfo, final String userId ){
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty( userInfo.getPictureUrl( ) )){
        imageLoader.get(userInfo.getPictureUrl( ), new ImageListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               mViewHolder.mUserIconImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_icon);
           }

           @Override
           public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
               Bitmap bitmap = null;
               if( TextUtils.isEmpty( userId ) || !userId.equals( userInfo.getUserId( ) ) ){
                   bitmap = response.getBitmap();
               }else{
                   bitmap = PersonalInfo.getCurrentUserIcon( mContext );
               }

               if (bitmap != null) {
                   Matrix matrix = new Matrix();  
                   matrix.postScale( 50.0f/bitmap.getWidth( ), 50.0f/bitmap.getHeight( ) );
                   Bitmap cutBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight( ), matrix, true); 

                   mViewHolder.mUserIconImg.setImageBitmap(BitmapUtils.toRoundBitmap( cutBitmap ));

                   if( null != cutBitmap && !cutBitmap.isRecycled( ) ){
                       cutBitmap.recycle( );
                   }

               } else {
                   mViewHolder.mUserIconImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_icon);
               }
           }
       }); 
    }else{
        mViewHolder.mUserIconImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_icon);
    }}

class ViewHolder{
    private RelativeLayout mScoreLayout = null;
    public TextView mPositionTxt = null;
    public TextView mUserNameTxt = null;
    public ImageView mUserIconImg = null;
    public TextView mUserScoreTxt = null;
}

private RequestQueue mQueue = null;  
private ImageLoader mImageLoader = null;
private Context mContext = null;
private String mUserId = null;
private Typeface mTypeface = null;
private ArrayList<UserScoreInfo> mUserInfoList = null;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = null;
private ViewHolder mViewHolder = null;
private int mMyPosition = -1;}
```

Comment: use `NetworkImageView` instead of ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first i do not think your program has any problem and i think this happens because the image has not completely downloaded from internet.In order to confirm this you can scroll the list and stop it suddenly to see if wrong images replace by correct one or not!! you can solve this problem by using placeholder image and error image in your request like this:

```
imageLoader.get(URL_IMAGE, ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                imageView, R.drawable.ico_loading, R.drawable.ico_error));
```

and my suggestion is using ImageLoader and NetworkImageView together for image request. for more information look at: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html

and another issue that is not relevant to your question is your usage of ViewHolder. you are using this design pattern wrongly and it dose not give you any performance. the concept of using this is to eliminate unnecessary call for findViewByID but for every row you call this function for every view. search net for more information.

Comment: because this list max size only 24 items,so i needn't use viewHolder in getView method.but In any case have to thank you.